# Can we use object destructuring for useState() in reactjs hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

As from the documentation from Hooks in Reactjs,

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

they use array destructuring. 
Can we use object destructuring in place of array destructuring?

Comment: so, for your example, `const {0:count, 1:setCount} = useState(0);` instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I totally agree with answer given by @Patrick.  Since react team implemented it adhere to all use cases. There's no need actually to put return values in object since it doesn't need to access it via keys or later need to update. One edge here is **Destructuring** part is way more easy for arrays than objects.

As we have seen `const [count, setCount] = useState(0);` we can use any name for count and setCount. In Objects we need to do it like this:

```
// grab the state value and setState func but rename them to count and setCount
   const { stateValue: count, setState: setCount } = useState(0);
```

in arrays:

```
// grab in order and rename at the same time
   const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

Answer (score 5):

[useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) returns an array, so no, in this case, you have to use array destructuring.

To clarify, this doesn't mean that all React hook functions need to return an array.

If you [create your own hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html), you can have it return whatever you like, including an object, which you can destructure.

Comment: why is it returning an array in useState() ? What's the motive ?

Comment: Since I'm not on the React core dev team, I don't know. I do recall there was some discussion going on about this on Twitter, but couldn't find it, would have included a link otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You should not for `useState`, but...

As @SakhiMansoor mentioned, naming variables become easy when destructuring array in case of `setState`, because it's generic hook and you can use it for different data, eg:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const [age, setAge] = useState(0);
...
```

But when creating custom hooks I usually prefer objects. Let's consider an example:

```
// If return an array
const [items, addItem, removeItem] = useItems();

// and only need `removeItem`, I write (I could easily forget one `,` here):
const [, , removeItem] = useItems();

// if I returned object, I would:
const { removeItem } = useItems();
```

When writing custom, specific hooks, I usually don't need to rename keys, so object  works better in this case.

Answer (score 0):

setDetails(prev => {
return {
...prev,
[e.target.name]:e.target.value
}
});

one of the best way.